# How to remove the command bar in Windows 10 File Explorer

Tags: windows-10-v1903

I tried using OldNewExplorer to remove the ribbon on the File explorer but it replaces the ribbon with the command bar, I'm using win10 1903 version. Tried the tweak using resourcehack to edit the shellstyle but it's not working for me.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The ribbon is not removable natively in Windows - it is built into Windows Explorer. The program you used is just an add-on to Explorer.

Go to the Ribbon, upper right beside the Help Icon and use the little UP arrow to hide the ribbon.

Uninstall the program you installed to remove the command bar.

That works well.

Comment: thanks for sharing, but I'm using a customized theme and I can't removed the command bar in the file explorer. If I removed the OldNewExplorer app it messes with the theme. please see the screenshot https://prnt.sc/s9hgtz

Comment: You may need to go to a plainer theme, remove OldNew, get back to normal, restart and then use your customized theme.

Answer (score 0):

The Ribbon can be totally removed from Explorer, but this requires a small third-party
program :
[Ribbon Disabler](https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.20).

It modifies a Windows file called `explorerframe.dll` but it makes a backup, for safety.

Download the program which a small archive called `RibbonDisabler.zip`.
Extract its contents and run the executable file `RibbonDisabler.exe`.
You will get the two options for disabling the Ribbon or re-enabling it.
To apply the modification a log off is required.

The end-result is that the Ribbon is disabled only for Explorer :

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing, but I already tried using Ribbondisabler but the command bar is still persistent. https://prnt.sc/s9hgtz that white bar is what i want to remove